# How to get an array's attribute with XML Twig

Tags: perl, xml-parsing, xml-twig

I've a XML file like this :

**cars.xml**

```
<root>
    <brand>
        <make i="1" n="Ford">
            <veh i="1" n="106">
            </veh>
            <veh i="2" n="107">
            </veh>
            <veh i="3" n="206">
            </veh>
        </make>
        <make i="2" n="GMC">
            <veh i="1" n="C3">
            </veh>
            <veh i="2" n="C4">
            </veh>
            <veh i="3" n="C5">
            </veh>
        </make>
        <make i="3" n="MERCEDES">
            <veh i="1" n="CLS">
            </veh>
            <veh i="2" n="SLS">
            </veh>
            <veh i="3" n="CLK">
            </veh>
        </make>
    </brand>
</root>
```

Then I've my perl code with XML::Twig and I would to add in an array all attributes "n" of "make" element... In others words I would an array formed by (FORD, GMC, MERCEDES)

I've a simple code bellow :but doesn't work ant I did not get which method to call in doc.

**init.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $file = "cars.xml";

my  $twig = new XML::Twig;
$twig -> parsefile($file);
$twig -> set_pretty_print('indented');

my $xml_root = $twig -> root;
my $xml_brand = $xml_root -> first_child('brand');
my $make_attribute = $xml_make -> att('n');
print $make_attribute . "\n";
```

Someone could to help me please ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want - use `get_xpath` (synonym of `findnodes`) to fetch all the `make` elements, and then use `map` to retrieve the `n` attribute

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;
use Data::Dumper;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile("cars.xml"); 

my @array_of_makes = map { $_ -> att('n') } $twig -> get_xpath('//make');

print Dumper \@array_of_makes;
```

Output:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'Ford',
          'GMC',
          'MERCEDES'
        ];
```